# Ayuda con botones y Switch en Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button menos;
    Button mas;
    Button reset;
    TextView resultado;
    Switch enden_apa;
    int contador = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mas = (Button)findViewById(R.id.botonMas);
        mas.setOnClickListener(this);
        menos = (Button)findViewById(R.id.botMenos);
        menos.setOnClickListener(this);
        reset = (Button)findViewById(R.id.reset);
        reset.setOnClickListener(this);
        resultado = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.conta);
        enden_apa = (Switch)findViewById(R.id.encen_apa);
        enden_apa.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.encen_apa:
                if (!enden_apa.isEnabled()) {
                    enden_apa.setChecked(false);
                    mas.setEnabled(false);
                    menos.setEnabled(false);
                    reset.setEnabled(false);

                } else if(enden_apa.isEnabled()) {
                    mas.setEnabled(true);
                    menos.setEnabled(true);
                    reset.setEnabled(true);
                    enden_apa.setChecked(true);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.botonMas:
                    contador ++;
                    resultado.setText(Integer.toString(contador));
                break;
            case R.id.botMenos:
                contador --;
                resultado.setText(Integer.toString(contador));
                break;
            case R.id.reset:
                contador = 0;
                resultado.setText(Integer.toString(contador));
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

Dado este código necesito que cuando se pulse el Switch los botones +, - y reset se pongan habilitados y cuando se apague el Switch se pongan deshabilitados. Lo he hecho de esta forma pero no funciona.

Answer (score 1):

El error se encuentra en :

```
enden_apa.isEnabled()
```

y debería ser :

```
enden_apa.isChecked()
```

No tienes que comprobar si esta activado o desactivado el "SWITCH" sino mas bien si ha sido presionado o no ha sido presionado.

> Por cierto esto es innecesario:
>
> ```
> enden_apa.setChecked(false);
> enden_apa.setChecked(true);
> ```